# Ascii compression for Git on MySQL backups

Tags: mysql, git, utf-8

I did mysql dump to dump.sql file with utf8, with Japanese and other foreign text etc.

This dump.sql is then 
git commit -m "increment backup"

My question is thus, is there a Ascii (utf8 safe) only compression that I can use for git backup considering git does incremental (delta backups) to modified lines only. Is shoco compression the answer? A smaz compression alternative. For git "delta / incremental save", can I save disk space with every git commit?

My rational for doing so is this:
Would like to save disk space on each delta git commit (efficiently compared with gz encoding which, according to delta save, will use more disk space in the long run) because mysql dump files can be really big

Please take utf8 encoding into consideration. For the mysql dump file, I did mysqldump with the -r option and my database is utf8 already.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump ... | gzip ... >dump.gz

gunzip ... <dump.gz | mysql ...
```

On Unix, at least, the uncompressed dump never touches the disk.  (I suspect Windows is dumb about pipes.)

Comment: gzip does not have any advantage for git's delta commit